# Why is the size of (void *) 8 bytes?

Tags: c, sizeof, void-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%ld", sizeof(void *));

    return 0;
}
```

The output for the program was `8`, but I am unable to figure out how.

Comment: Because thats the size of a `void*`.

Comment: If the exam was asking you what the result of the program would be without any qualification, then the exam wasn't posed properly. The result of `sizeof(void*)` is dependent on the architecture for which you are compiling and `%ld` is also the wrong `printf` specifier. It should be `%zu` instead. So worst case this has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program outputs `8` because your target is a 64-bit system with 8-bit bytes where pointers are 64-bit wide, hence occupy 8 bytes.

`sizeof(void *)` is the size in bytes of a generic pointer.  The value depends on the platform. I have seen different ones where it was `1`, `2`, `4` or `8`, but other values are possible, albeit highly unlikely.

Note that `sizeof()` expressions evaluate to the type `size_t` which is not the same as `long int` (especially on Windows 64-bit platforms, where `long int` only has 32 bits). You should use `%zu` to print a value of this type and output a trailing newline for clarity.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(void *));
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what the precise question was, but if asked what the output should be, here is a long answer:

- depending on the platform, the output can be `8` or `4` or even `2` or `1`, or some other value.
- if type `size_t` is not the same as `unsigned long`, the behavior is undefined, anything can happen.
- on some older systems, no output might appear at all because of the missing newline.
- if running the program from the C-shell, the output may be very surprising: `4%` or `8%`.

The proper format is `%zu`, but for maximum portability to pre-c99 systems, here is an alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(void *));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One byte pointers seems kinda impractical.

Comment: @StephenC: it is the case of some DSP processors that lack byte addressability.  `char`, `short`, `int`, `long` and `void *` are all 32-bit bytes, or possibly even 64-bit bytes.

Comment: Ah ... I see.  Never come across that before.

Comment: @StephenC: I meant *that lack 8-bit byte addressability*